# No output in console chrome inspect element (Webpack configuring )

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code

Hello I am unable to see output in my chrome inspect element. Following are my files.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhn3E.jpg)

[Webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOuXj.jpg)

```
const path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
      entry: ["./src/js/index.js"],
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
      }
    };
```

[PACKAGE JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SulP0.jpg)

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "Gaurav Yadav guided by Jonas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

[TEST.JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os28l.jpg)

```
 console.log("Export data");
    export default 23;
```

[INDEX.JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEiAn.jpg)

```
// Global app controller
import num from "./test";
console.log(`${num} from test`);
```

[dist/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6m8u.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      src = "js/bundle.js";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My project folder name is **FORKIFY**. There are *three subfolders* **dist, src , nodemodules** and *three files* **pacakage-lock.json, pacakage.json, webpack.config.js**. Directory image [dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3UCA.jpg).
Please let me know why my console in empty ?
 I was following this video to code

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBEryysS1Tg&list=PL15NLmjJalxydhO9orvXv_yvgZEfrDQvX&index=127

Where is the problem and in which file ??
Do i need to change my webpack config file ?

Comment: Is your index.html file within the `dist` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure is incorrect.

```
const path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
      entry: ["./src/js/index.js"],
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
      }
    };
```

The `dist` folder will get created when you run the `webpack` command and you have mentioned your `index.html` file is present in the `dist` folder.

Place your `index.html` file at the root level of your project. Also, if `js` is folder within `dist`, then add slash to treat as a directory i:e `path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js/")`

Appropriate Folder Structure

```
node_modules
src
 -js
  - index.js
index.html
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

// webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js/')
    },
    watch: true
}
```

// index.js

```
console.log('logging');
```

// index.html

```
<h1>WebPack works!!</h1>
<script src="dist/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Run command `webpack`, which will create `bundle.js` file within `dist/js/` folder and then open your `index.html` file in the browser.

Comment: I tried it still does not show any output. Structure of my DIR now
 https://imgur.com/MwOTrx6

Comment: why there are two `index.html` files? Check, whether you have included proper path to your `bundle.js` file in `index.html` file. It is running properly on my machine.

Comment: Yes it is same. I just followed the YouTube video but it's not working in my machine

Comment: That html fine contains something esle. Can you please look at that video i shared in my question

Comment: Hey its running now I don't know how, but it is running now thanks for responding